# Applying style on specific row in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to loop through `tr` in my Angular application code and need to apply style to a specific row.  I would have several such rows.

For e.g

```html
<tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1">
         <td style="padding:6px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;">{{row[0]}}</td>
         <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1" style="padding:6px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;">{{cell | shortAndBlankNumberFormat: 2}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

This will be the actual content. I would need to search for that row    that contains `Net Premiums Written` and apply class `net-cost`.

```html
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Direct premiums written</td>
      <td>33,150,000</td>
      <td>33,813,000</td>
      <td>35,179,045 </td>
      <td>35,882,626 </td>   
      <td>35,882,626 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Assumed premiums written</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>  
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="net-cost">Net Premiums Written</td>
      <td class="net-cost">-</td>
      <td class="net-cost">-</td>
      <td class="net-cost">-</td>
      <td class="net-cost">-</td> 
      <td class="net-cost">-</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] == 'Net Premiums Written'}">
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```css
.net-cost {
   background: #FF0000;
}
```

If you want to match more than one string you can do as:

```html
[ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] == 'Net Premiums Written' || row[0] == 'any other string' || row[0] == 'some more to match'}"
```

Comment: What do i do if there are four rows and need to apply the same style

Comment: [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] == 'Net Premiums Written' || 'any other string' || 'some more to match'}"

Comment: @Tom it will add class `net-cost` in `tr` wherever it finds matching text in `row[0]`

Comment: @Tom did it help?

Comment: || doesnt seem to work. Works only when i give one string